# MAAS KVM failed commissioning a node: Node operation 'Commissioning' timed out after 30 minutes

Tags: virtualization, maas, kvm-virtualization, qemu

**Update**

I found out that right before the prompt for login, the ephemeral image flashes a message saying "[Can not apply stage config, no datasource found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/72gK4.png)". After some research, it might have to do with the node not being able to reach the region controller as a result of network misconfiguration.
The nodes are on a virtual network configured at 10.17.17.0/24, while MAAS server is deployed at 10.10.9.34

How should I correct my network configuration?

rackd.log

```
2020-01-23 16:02:46 provisioningserver.rackdservices.http: [info] ipxe.cfg requested by 10.17.17.191
2020-01-23 16:02:46 provisioningserver.rackdservices.http: [info] ipxe.cfg-52:54:00:bb:ce:ad requested by 10.17.17.191
2020-01-23 16:02:46 provisioningserver.rackdservices.http: [info] /images/ubuntu/amd64/generic/bionic/daily/boot-kernel requested by 10.17.17.191
2020-01-23 16:02:46 provisioningserver.rackdservices.http: [info] /images/ubuntu/amd64/generic/bionic/daily/boot-initrd requested by 10.17.17.191
2020-01-23 16:02:55 provisioningserver.rackdservices.http: [info] /images/ubuntu/amd64/generic/bionic/daily/squashfs requested by 10.17.17.191
```

regiond.log

```
2020-01-23 16:02:04 regiond: [info] 127.0.0.1 GET /MAAS/rpc/ HTTP/1.1 --> 200 OK (referrer: -; agent: provisioningserver.rpc.clusterservice.ClusterClientService)
2020-01-23 16:02:19 maasserver.rpc.leases: [info] Lease update: expiry for 10.17.17.191 on 52:54:0:bb:ce:ad at 2020-01-23 16:02:19
2020-01-23 16:02:23 maasserver.region_controller: [info] Reloaded DNS configuration; ip 10.17.17.191 released
2020-01-23 16:02:32 maasserver.rpc.leases: [info] Lease update: commit for 10.17.17.191 on 52:54:0:bb:ce:ad at 2020-01-23 16:02:32 (lease time: 30s)
2020-01-23 16:02:34 regiond: [info] 127.0.0.1 GET /MAAS/rpc/ HTTP/1.1 --> 200 OK (referrer: -; agent: provisioningserver.rpc.clusterservice.ClusterClientService)
2020-01-23 16:02:36 maasserver.region_controller: [info] Reloaded DNS configuration; ip 10.17.17.191 connected to golden-bee on eth0
2020-01-23 16:02:55 maasserver.rpc.leases: [info] Lease update: commit for 10.17.17.191 on 52:54:0:bb:ce:ad at 2020-01-23 16:02:55 (lease time: 600s) (hostname: golden-bee)
2020-01-23 16:03:00 maasserver.rpc.leases: [info] Lease update: commit for 10.17.17.191 on 52:54:0:bb:ce:ad at 2020-01-23 16:03:00 (lease time: 600s) (hostname: ubuntu)
2020-01-23 16:03:00 maasserver.models.dnsresource: [info] Updated dynamic hostname 'ubuntu.maas'. Added IP address 'sip.ip'.
2020-01-23 16:03:04 maasserver.region_controller: [info] Reloaded DNS configuration; ip 10.17.17.191 linked to resource ubuntu on zone maas
2020-01-23 16:03:04 regiond: [info] 127.0.0.1 GET /MAAS/rpc/ HTTP/1.1 --> 200 OK (referrer: -; agent: provisioningserver.rpc.clusterservice.ClusterClientService)
2020-01-23 16:03:34 regiond: [info] 127.0.0.1 GET /MAAS/rpc/ HTTP/1.1 --> 200 OK (referrer: -; agent: provisioningserver.rpc.clusterservice.ClusterClientService)
2020-01-23 16:04:04 regiond: [info] 127.0.0.1 GET /MAAS/rpc/ HTTP/1.1 --> 200 OK (referrer: -; agent: provisioningserver.rpc.clusterservice.ClusterClientService)
2020-01-23 16:04:34 regiond: [info] 127.0.0.1 GET /MAAS/rpc/ HTTP/1.1 --> 200 OK (referrer: -; agent: provisioningserver.rpc.clusterservice.ClusterClientService)
2020-01-23 16:05:04 regiond: [info] 127.0.0.1 GET /MAAS/rpc/ HTTP/1.1 --> 200 OK (referrer: -; agent: provisioningserver.rpc.clusterservice.ClusterClientService)
```

Some of the consulted sources:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/maas/+bug/1665459
https://bugs.launchpad.net/maas/+bug/1666719
https://answers.launchpad.net/maas/+question/196791

**Original question**

I have MAAS 2.7 and I'm trying to commission a node composed using KVM, the commissioning process always gets stuck at "loading ephemeral", then times out after 30 minutes.

When I look into the VM, it's hanging on a [ubuntu login screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VXFIs.png) after the PXE boot and I have no idea what to enter, I have tried many possible combinations of credentials but it always shows "login incorrect". After reboot/re-commission, it would go through the PXE boot -> prompt for login process again.

I probably messed up in my network configuration: the MAAS server is deployed on a physical machine, then I created a virtual network using virt manager on the same machine, and have added the ssh key on the virtual network. DHCP is enabled on this virtual network through MAAS.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly a fix, but I finally got it to work by downgrading MAAS to 2.6